# Connecting two servers using unix domain sockets

Tags: ruby, sockets, unix, unicorn, thin

Ruby web servers like [Thin](http://code.macournoyer.com/thin/) and [Unicorn](http://unicorn.bogomips.org/) are often used behind an Nginx (as reverse proxy). This configuration has the advantage that the Nginx Server is independent of the Ruby version, and can act additionally as a proxy for static files. They are usually connected to each other by a [unix domain socket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket), because it is faster than a TCP loopback connection. The question is if you have an application which consists of two parts, say frontend and backend or client and server, is it possible to **connect two Unicorn or two Thin servers** by a unix domain socket, like this:

```
nginx => thin (Frontend) --(unix domain socket)--> thin (backend)
```

Answer (score 1):

App server sockets created only for proxy-to-app/app-to-proxy communication. There is no way to communicate between apps.

You should to create frontend app for communicate your API(backend). You can use nginx for this purposes so.

Just make a two upstreams in nginx config

```
upstream frontend {
    server unix:/path/to/frontend/rails/app/tmp/thin.socket;
}

upstream backend {
    server unix:/path/to/backend/rails/app/tmp/thin.socket;
}
```

and use it in server section

```
server { 
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://frontend;
    }

    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://backend;
    }
}
```

i hope it helps